# Problemas con variable de SESSION y paginación en PHP

Tags: php, session

Tengo una consulta de registros y los quiero mostrar con una paginación (sin usar plugins) el problema radica que uso una variable de sesión para realizar la consulta, en la primera página me de da bien los datos pero al acceder a la página 2 me muestra los siguientes errores:

> Notice : Undefined variable: _SESSION in  C:\xampp\htdocs\tick\includes\recordatorios.php on line  5
>
> Notice : Trying to get property of non-object in  C:\xampp\htdocs\tick\includes\recordatorios.php on line  8

Dejo el código que uso para ver si me pueden dar una luz de mi error. Saludos

```
session_start();
$usuarioCreado = $_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'];
$query1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM recordatorio WHERE status=1 AND FK_idUsuario = $usuarioCreado");
$totalRegistros = $query1->num_rows;

if($totalRegistros>0){

    #Numero de registros por página
    $rowsPerPage = 10;

    #Mostrar la página por defualt.
    $pageNum = 1;

    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        //sleep(1);
        $pageNum = $_GET['page'];           
    }


    $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
    $total_paginas = ceil($totalRegistros / $rowsPerPage);

    $query2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM recordatorio WHERE status=1 AND FK_idUsuario = $usuarioCreado ORDER BY fechaVencimiento ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");

    $x=1;
    while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()){
        if($x%2==0){
            echo '
            <ul class="notes">
                <li>
                    <div class="rotate-2" style="background:'.$row['color'].'">
                    <p style="border:dotted 1px">'.$row['fechaVencimiento'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$row['descripcion'].'</p>
                    <p class="creado">Creado: '.$row['fechaInicio'].'</p>                                               
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleliminarRecordatorio" type="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="eliminarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></a>                                           
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleditarRecordatorio" type="button" title="Editar" onclick="editarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>                                            
                    <br>
                    </div>
                </li>                              
            </ul>';
        }else{
            echo'               
            <ul class="notes">
                <li>
                    <div class="rotate-1" style="background:'. $row['color'].'">
                    <p style="border:dotted 1px">'.$row['fechaVencimiento'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$row['descripcion'].'</p>
                    <p class="creado">Creado: '.$row['fechaInicio'].'</p>                                               
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleliminarRecordatorio" type="button" title="Eliminar" onclick="eliminarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></a>                                           
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleditarRecordatorio" type="button" title="Editar" onclick="editarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>                                            
                    <br>
                    </div>
                </li>                              
            </ul>';
        }       
    $x++;       
    }

    if($total_paginas > 1){ 
        echo '<div class="col-lg-12" >';
        echo '<div class="float-right">';
        echo '<nav>';
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';                     
                if($pageNum != 1)
                    echo '<li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link" data="'.($pageNum-1).'">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            Anterior
                        </a></li>';
                for($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){
                    if($pageNum == $i){
                        echo '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }                           
                    else{
                        echo '<li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link" data="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }                           
                }
                if($pageNum != $total_paginas)
                    echo '<li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link" data="'.($pageNum+1).'">Siguiente
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        </a></li>';                 
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';      
    }           
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido solucionar el problema cambiando el siguiente fragmento de código...

```
session_start();
```

Por

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
```